# return render with get_context_data()

Tags: django

The scenario is I'm trying to render a specific class section and list of students that doesn't belong to any sections yet.

How can I achieve this using function based views?

Here's my code that doesn't work but at least this is the idea:

```
def get_students(request, pk):
    section = Section.objects.get(id=pk)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(get_students(request, pk), self).get_context_data(pk)
        context['section'] = section
        context['students'] = Account.objects.filter(Q(is_student=True) | Q(is_assigned=False)).order_by(
        'last_name', 'first_name')

        return context

    return render(request, 'driver-list-modal.html', get_context_data(pk))
```

The template that I picture would contain the class section name and a table of unassigned students with a checkbox to include them to that section if selected.

Thank you for answering!

Comment: Why do you even need `get_context_data` there? Just make a dictionary and pass that as the context? Plus you use that function as if it were part of a class (calling `super`, etc.) but it is **not** part of one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In class based views the view class has a method `get_context_data` which returns a *dictionary* (key-value pairs) which we want to use as the *context* for the template.

You try to write a *function* inside your view and use it as if your view was a class based view by using `self` as a parameter and calling `super`. This of course will give you an error as `get_students` is **not a class**. What you need to do is simply create a dictionary and pass that as the context:

```
def get_students(request, pk):
    section = Section.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {
        'section': section,
        'students': Account.objects.filter(Q(is_student=True) | Q(is_assigned=False)).order_by('last_name', 'first_name')
    }
    return render(request, 'driver-list-modal.html', context)
```